# Having two scales in chart using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 to create a chart with two scales on y axis one towards left and other towards right of the graph.

On Left Y Axis I am trying to plot Revenue vs Date and on right I am trying to plot Clicks vs Date.

The max value for Revenue is let say $1800 and for clicks is 4000.
The blue line is the revenue line and orange line is the clicks.

Can someone help me how can I get the orange line fit in the same y domain?

Code I am using for Revenue is:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([min_y_value, max_y_value])
    .range([height - margin, margin]);

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([start_date, end_date])
    .range([0 + margin, width - margin]);

var color = d3.scale.category10().range();

var vis = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var g = vis.append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+margin+",0)");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d,i) {
        return x(get_date(d.date));
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d[trend]);
    });

for(var i = 0; i < report.length; i++) {
    g.append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", line(report[i]))
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", color[i % 10])
        .attr("id", "line-"+report[i][0]['offer_name'])
        .attr("stroke-width", 2);
}
```

Code I am using for Clicks is

```
var trend1 = 'clicks';
var max_y1_value = max_min['max_'+trend1];
var min_y1_value = max_min['min_'+trend1];
var y1_range = max_y1_value - min_y1_value;
var y1_interval_value = Math.floor(y1_range/yticks);

max_y1_value = max_y_value + y_interval_value;
min_y1_value = (min_y_value - y_interval_value > 0)?(min_y_value - y_interval_value) : 0;

var y1 = d3.scale.linear().domain([min_y1_value, max_y1_value]).range([height - margin, margin]);
var x1 = d3.time.scale().domain([start_date, end_date]).range([0 + margin, width - margin]);
console.log('max_y_value : '+max_y_value+'  min_y_value : '+min_y_value+'    max_y1_value : '+max_y1_value+'  min_y1_value : '+min_y1_value+'   trend1: '+trend1);
var line1 = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d,i) {
        return x1(get_date(d.date));
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        console.log(d[trend1]+'    '+y1(d[trend1]));
        return y1(d[trend1]);
    });

for(var i = 0; i < report.length; i++) {
    g.append("svg:path")
        .attr("d", line1(report[i]))
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", color[i + report.length % 10])
        .attr("id", "line1-"+report[i][0]['offer_name'])
        .attr("stroke-width", 2);
}
```

[Chart Image](http://tinypic.com/r/fa3cp5/5)

**Can someone help me how can I get the orange line fit in the same y domain?**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are overwriting your `max_y1_value` and `min_y1_value` with the values from the other series. For example, you first define `max_y1_value`:

```
var max_y1_value = max_min['max_'+trend1];
```

And then later you replace with with another value:

```
max_y1_value = max_y_value + y_interval_value;
```

I recommend using [d3.extent](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_extent) to compute the domain from data.